# How to convert Apache's RewriteCond and RewriteRule to Nginx configuration?

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, webserver

I have the following code in `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,B,QSA]
```

I need to convert it to `Nginx` config. Based on an online website, converted it like this:

```
location / {
   if (!-e $request_filename){
     rewrite ^/([\s\S]*)$ /index.php?rt=$1 break;
   }
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

But it doesn't work. I mean, when I click on the internal link of the website, a file gets downloaded and the browser blocks it. I don't know why this happens :)

Any idea how can I convert those `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` to Nginx's config?

Comment: What do you mean by "a file gets downloaded and the browser blocks it"?

Comment: Usually you don't actually need such rewriting rules for nginx. Actually the nginx documentation clearly states that if one does need such rules, then one has made a mistake in the setup ;-) Instead take a look at what the typical directive `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;` actually does, how it works. You will find tons of examples for that.

Comment: So I suggest that you either share your solution as an answer here or delete this question. Because as it stands now it does not help anyone. Does it?

Answer (score 1):

I did it using the following code in the Nginx config file:

```
location ~ "^/([\s\S]*)$" {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?rt=$1;
}
```